# Can you steal the show?

Tags: reverse-puzzling

<sub>This is an entry into the [16<sup>th</sup> Fortnightly Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/fortnightly-topic-challenge-16-reverse-puzzling) -  [reverse-puzzling](/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling)</sub>

---

My friend just received a letter telling him he made it onto a really famous TV show, 
**and he won't tell me which!**

All he gave me was his plan of what to do on the show, and said I should be able to work it out from that:

[image: problem]

## **What show is my friend going on?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like the infamous

> Monty Hall problem

to me.

So

> W and L denote winning and losing doors; C and S denote changing door and staying with the same door; and the fact that following "C" edges leads to two W and one L, while following "S" edges leads to two L and one W, indicates that when Monty opens a losing door you should then change to the other one.

So the show is

> Let's Make a Deal.

Comment: That is correct, can you add reasoning?

Comment: Was already doing (and adding the name of the show, which was the single thing actually asked for and which I'd omitted). Better now?

Comment: Yes thanks, didn't actually know the show! Just was looking for Monty Hall :P

Comment: I thought of this, I just could not make of any sense of the letters. Nicely done!

Comment: But what if [I want a goat](https://xkcd.com/1282/)?

Comment: @Will, then you can switch if you get the car or stay if you get a goat :P